# PowerMock MockStatic expect not working for EasyMock anyObject

Tags: easymock, powermock

This seems ok

```
EasyMock.expect(URLDecoder.decode("test", "UTF-8")).andThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException("This is a test"));
```

This doesn't

```
EasyMock.expect(URLDecoder.decode((String) EasyMock.anyObject(), "UTF-8")).andThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException("This is a test"));
```

This throws the following

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception usually occurs when matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a  method:
foo(5, eq(6));  // wrong
You need to use no matcher at all or a matcher for every single param:
foo(eq(5), eq(6));  // right
foo(5, 6);  // also right
at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.createMissingMatchers(ExpectedInvocation.java:47)
at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.<init>(ExpectedInvocation.java:40)
at org.easymock.internal.RecordState.invoke(RecordState.java:78)
at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
at
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use 1 matcher in your expectation, then you need to use all matchers.

Sadly, this isn't explained very well in the error message you get out of EasyMock, but adding an `EasyMock.eq()` arround the other string should do the trick.

```
EasyMock.expect(URLDecoder.decode((String) EasyMock.anyObject(), EasyMock.eq("UTF-8"))).andThrow(new UnsupportedEncodingException("This is a test"));
```